# How do we configure data source(S3) and data targets(Redshift cluster) in (cloudformation) for aws glue job

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

i have created s3 for raw data,configured JSON classifier and the crawler.
created redshift cluster and created connection in Glue.
Unable to Configure ETL Job With S3 as Data Source(specific to path on S3) and redshift as data target using cloudformation which is the requirement.
can anyone please guide me through.

Comment: what is the error/issue encountered?

Comment: Got it solved thank you!